# Application or Service to do some tasks in specific time slot

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-services

I've scenario to create an application(Windows service , Winforms app) which runs twice every day automatically on users PC. These Users are internal employees in the same network. So at morning and evening this application has to run. But it doesn't need to show any window or information saying its running. Its good to have a simple notification in system tray that its started execution.

My experience in with web application development. So I got a little stucked with these such application on deciding which is best.What my understandings are if its a standalone exe, we could ask all users to download the exe and install. 
If its a windows service we may depend up on instalutil to install the service.

So I really needs an advice on this. The application is nothing, just requesting a TFS api and the resulting JSON has to store in Table. So the JSOn will be based on each user using their windows authentication.

Please suggest a good solution to achieve its the best,secure and easiest way even for non tech savvy users.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all user communicating to TFS server twice a day i guess better way is to install a service in one centralized machine which will run a window service twice a day and that machine will host that service using WCF so that other user will communicate with machine this will help you to distribute the load of tfs api. i used the same approach in my case where one machine talk to ALM and other talk to that machine to get the files.

Creating a window service is pretty simple and straight forward. 
Follow the link to make one:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-C-Sharp/

You can host the service in WCF using IIS, TCP, Webservice, Console application its upto you. Follow this link

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/550796/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-How-to-Host-a-WCF-Service

I guess i helped you :)

Comment: Sorry because of lack of knowledge in windows apps and wcf, I have a little questions.. the JSON returned from the TFS API is different for different users. If I logged into my machine it returns the entries for me. Same way if someone else logged in it returns result only for them.. But how can we make it possible if its on a single machine since it requires users logins to get their details... Also how could this be automated.. what I understood from your explanation is it require some request from the user to fetch API or the user has to specify their credentials every time??

Comment: ok i wasn't aware of this scenario.I dont think my initial approach will work in this case  although you can setup the single machine with everyone credentials but i'm afraid users wont like their credentials to be shared for that.(only if tfs is not mapped to particular systems). well in this case its better to install the service to each machine and schedule the timer of the service to run in an interval of 6 hrs like your requirement.

Comment: OK.. got you friend... Anyway I like those info you shared

Comment: another approach is that single machine will fetch JSON for all the user as it will have list of credential with it and then WCF will post the result (JSON) to any localhost server so that every user can just access that endpoint from their browser and download it. It totally depends upon the architecture you want to work with. And no manual intervention is required from any user to call api. only they will have to hit the end point to get their result

Comment: OK.. But the issue is then the user has to open some URLs.. So to avoid URLs to be opened (Ofcourse require manual intervention), I guess windows service will work best

Comment: how about storing the  details of each user in that centralized  machine with username,password and the folder of their system where they want the json. So  that after each api call for the particular user it will copy the json to that folder.

Comment: Sorry that could be Against policies.. since those are windows credentials..  Anyway am proceeding with windows service..